# Rounding floating point number

Tags: floating-point, rounding

I have a number with an exponent field of 4 and a fraction field of 5.

The number I need to round is −(1.0110101)2, and I have to round down, round up, round to zero, round nearest.

So I have -(1.0110101) = -(1.01101|01), but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notation you are using. Could you describe what the symbols represent? I'd guess '-' is sign, while '(' and ')' bound the fraction bits, but how do I interpret the '|'?

Comment: Also, consider reviewing the meta post on homework to help you ask these questions better in the future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @codekaizen  sorry the - is a negative sign, and exactly the fraction bound the bits, and the | separates the fraction field bits from the guard and sticky bits